# How do I make conditional statements using data in a select_tag in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to get a conditional statement to compare values between different rows in an Active Record table. I have a select_tag that gives 2 options being the name of the rows. For example I have two characters "Steve", and "Tom" and their names are the values of the select_tag. I wanna be able to do something if they select Steve and I want it to do something else if they choose "Tom." How do I do this with the code that I have?

```
<%= form_tag("/myaction", method: "get") do %>
<p>Select a Character</p>
<hr>
<%= @select_window = select_tag "characters", options_from_collection_for_select(@characters, "id", "name"), prompt: "Select a character:" %>
<% end %>
```

End game, I'm trying to to take two values and do calculations using them but I need to know what numbers I'm working with by narrowing it down by the character selected.

Any tips helps!

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you want to do? And do you want to do it after clicking submit button?

Comment: @J.Krzus There's a table of frame data for characters and I want to add the frame data from one character to anothers. But I don't know how to do logic with select_tags cause I need to be able to know what's selected.

Comment: I don't have much time tonight to explain but in short you could add a submit button and then in the controller you will receive params with the character id like `params[:id]` then you can do your logic there. (Controller is not the place you would keep logic in professional app, but if you just started learning rails it will be ok). Also i'd use `form_with` instead of form_tags https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html